# How to find out if class has DataContract attribute?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontract, deserialization

I'm writing a serialization function that needs to determine whether class has DataContract attribute. Basically function will use DataContractSerializer if class has DataContract attribute, otherwise it will use XmlSerializer.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simplest way to test for DataContractAttribute is probably:

```
bool f = Attribute.IsDefined(typeof(T), typeof(DataContractAttribute));
```

That said, now that DC supports POCO serialization, it is not complete. A more complete test for DC serializability would be:

```
bool f = true;
try {
    new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
}
catch (DataContractException) {
    f = false;
}
```

Comment: Set this answer as accepted because I don't have to get all attributes.

Comment: I could only get the second example to compile using an `InvalidDataContractException`.

Answer (score 7):

```
    bool hasDataContractAttribute = typeof(YourType)
         .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataContractAttribute), true).Any();
```

Comment: Nice answer. In LINQ, it's generally better to use `Any()` than `Count() > 0` for both performance and readability, but in this case it's an academic distinction.

Comment: If you have an object of the class, better to replace typeof(YourType)
with this.GetType()

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
object o = this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true).ToList().FirstOrDefault(e => e is DataContractAttribute);

bool hasDataContractAttribute = (o != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that in addition to checking for DataContractAttribute, you should also allow for System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute and System.SerializableAttribute.

```
bool canDataContractSerialize = (from x in value.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true)
                                 where x is System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute
                                 | x is System.SerializableAttribute
                                 | x is System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttributex).Any;
```